# Can a process builder trigger itself for a second time (after an initial trigger)?

Tags: process-builder

I have a process builder which is triggered by a field update. This update fulfills criteria so some immediate actions are taken. One of these is an update to a field which should then trigger the process builder again. Should this work?

(first time poster, if there is anything I should add or change about my question: please let me know!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have checked the Recursion Checkbox in the Process Builder, Your trigger may fire recursively.

Another situation would be having multiple process builder which fires each other by updating the fields used in entry criteria.

Check these references:-

1. [When to use Recursion Checkbox in Process Builder](https://sf9to5.com/2019/09/17/when-use-recursion-checkbox-process-builder/)
2. [Process Builder Advanced Option Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_advanced_considerations.htm&type=5)
3. [Process Builder: how to make recursion work](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116326/process-builder-how-to-make-recursion-work)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That really helped me out!